# file() не ищет искомое in_array

Tags: php, массивы

есть файл. 19.08.2020.txt (их много по датам)
в файле есть строки, все вида:

```
260343402285629500011
260343402285629500012
260343402285629500013
```

ну и т.д.
числа могут быть меньше или больше знаков на 5 или 10.

считываю в массив

```
 $a = file( '19.08.2020.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
```

пытаюсь найти в массиве

```
$b = '260343402285629500013';
if( in_array( $b, $a ) ) ...
if( in_array( $b, $a, true ) ) ...
```

нет искомого... false
но строка с числом точно есть, есть и в массиве с ключем 2, и ищется точно она...

если число в длину не более 5-11 цифр то все ок... но у меня числа длинные могут быть. как быть?

Comment: В файле у вас наверняка есть перевод строки. Пользуйте trim. Дампните $a и посмотрите на предмет \n .

Comment: да в том то и прикол. trim есть. вардамп array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "260343402285629500016" }

Answer (score 0):

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php):

```
array_map('intval', $a);
```